# how to update openstreetmap (OSM) with android app

Tags: android, openstreetmap

I am looking for how easily one can contribute to openstreetmap. So I was searching for an app on android that can take my GPS  track or while I travel it should update the openstreetmap.
I checked [OsmAnd](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.osmand&hl=en) and [OSMTracker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.guillaumin.android.osmtracker&hl=en) and many more but could not find this functionality.
But I feel there must be some simple app through which I can contribute to openstreetmap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A GPX track doesn't automatically lead to a data update of OSM. It just solves as an additional data source when editing the map manually (see [these](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/5440/why-arent-my-gps-traces-shown-on-the-maps) [questions](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/938/can-not-see-the-gps-track)).

Furthermore both OsmAnd and OSMTracker are able to upload a track to OSM as far as I know.

For further questions read the [beginner's guide](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Beginners%27_Guide) or visit [help.openstreetmap.org](http://help.openstreetmap.org/).